# Why is the color of a bounty number in the "Reputation" tab dark green (not white)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounty

I recently just looked at my "Reputation" tab, and realized that it's so hard to read the bounty number since it is so dark, here is an image:

[image]

I am just curious if this is a bug or not, if so, why is it like this?

The one in the bottom will be good:

[image]

Also after-all, I have a feeling that it is because it's merging the colors of all things under by order, so the color keeps changing, and the last value in the list is green text, so the bounty text will be also green, that's my feeling.

@JustCarty provides a good answer but I would be happier if this was implemented into the site.

Also, I realized if I click on "time" tab on the "bounty" page, it will show perfectly:

[image]

So by all means it's a very strange issue.

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328559/369403)

Comment: @ErikA No answer tho :-)

Comment: I came across it too

Comment: Yup @zixuan :-)

Comment: @YaakovEllis It's been two months of [meta-tag:status-review] already, can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Thanks for your patience and to @JustCarty for your work in suggesting a fix.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it Yaakov

Answer (score 26):

I have just had a quick look through the CSS and there is an overriding rule in the secondary.css file:

```
.user-show-new .user-rep-full .rep-up {
    color: #45A163;
}
```

The matching part being the `.rep-up`, therefore if we adjust that rule slightly to read:

```
.user-show-new .user-rep-full .rep-up:not(.bounty-indicator-tab) {
    color: #45A163;
}
```

It will then show a blue background with white text which is a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, but first of all i want the site to be edited, i know you can fix it in CSS code, but i would like the site to be edited

Comment: @U9-Forward I appreciate that, and to be honest, I wasn't offering a way to locally rewrite the CSS (I never use those). I think I was mainly just writing the issue to make it easier for the Devs to make the change.

Comment: @U9-Forward you can wait for the site to be editted (or never be edited), or you can add your own css style with an extension.

Comment: `:not()` isn't supported in IE6.. so this ain't gonna work..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, I’ve thought about that - it was only introduced in IE9 - and was considering altering my answer to recommend the removal of the `rep-up` class on the `bounty-indicator-tab`...

Comment: He's joking about IE6 (or at least, I sure hope so).

Comment: @thirtydot I’m working for a client who’s still using IE7 so I’m used to stupid requests like that 

Comment: @thirtydot i was .. indeed x_x