# Bounty reputation icon has unintended style on user's Reputation tab

Tags: bug, design, bounty

The style of the icon looks odd:

[image]

The style is from `secondary.css` and the text's color matches the same one like the green reputation icon:

```
.user-show-new .user-rep-full .rep-up {
    color: #45A163;
}
```

Reproducible on (haven't tried Mozilla):

- Chrome, version `74.0.3729.169` (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Internet Explorer, version `11.765.17134.0`
- Mozilla Firefox `66.0.3` (64-bit)

Comment: Similar recent [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385529/why-is-the-color-of-a-bounty-number-in-the-reputation-tab-dark-green-not-whit).

Comment: Not so much "wrong style" as "unintended style" :-)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I am far from a native speaker, yet trying my best :) However, unintended implies wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: "Unintended" implies "unforeseen", whether useful or not. As one famous character said: "Prepare for unforeseen consequences!" I'm pretty sure the blue background for bounties and the green foreground for upvotes are intended; whoever did them just didn't predict that they would _Combine_